# How to display icons in JHipster 5?

Tags: jhipster

I'm trying to add/change Font Awesome icon in JHipster 5 app.
I can print only icons that already in default template.

I can change:

```
   <fa-icon [icon]="'home'"></fa-icon>
            <span>
                <span jhiTranslate="global.menu.home">Home</span>
            </span>
```

to:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="'asterisk'"></fa-icon>
                <span>
                    <span jhiTranslate="global.menu.home">Home</span>
                </span>
```

but can't change to

```
<fa-icon [icon]="'tv'"></fa-icon>
                <span>
                    <span jhiTranslate="global.menu.home">Home</span>
                </span>
```

or any other icon.
Are they defined in some place?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Icons are in `src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts`, here you can add new icons.

Comment: this is the right file, however, is there a documentation on this?  A link perhaps?

Comment: No, there's no documentation about it yet.

Answer (score 4):

To complete Alexandre answer ;

Example to add the twitter icon :

(in "jhipsterVersion": "5.1.0")

> read node_modules/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome/README.md

1. `yarn add @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons` in `src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts`
2. declare your icon :

.

```
import { faTwitter } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
library.add(faTwitter);
```

3. in your html, use and don't forget to tell it is from fab (Brand)

.

```
<fa-icon [icon]="['fab', 'twitter']"></fa-icon>
```

4. Maybe you should also re-run webpack:build. But for me it worked directly

(see the top of of `src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts`)

```
/* after changing this file run 'yarn run webpack:build' */
```

Answer (score 4):

For Jhipster 6 the file to define icons to be used is
src/main/webapp/app/core/icons/font-awesome-icons.ts:

```
import { faAmazon } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
export const fontAwesomeIcons = [
    faAmazon,
    faUser,
    ...
```

and remember to refer to the icon with (note 'fab' instead of 'fa' for brands icons):

```
<fa-icon [icon]="['fab', 'amazon']"></fa-icon>
```

If you plan to include brands free icons (amazon icon is there) you should also install the npm package:

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
```

Answer (score 0):

If you tried to add your icons like so:

`vendor.ts`

```
import {
    // other imports
    faFileSignature,
    faLock
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

// other imports
library.add(faFileSignature);
library.add(faLock);
```

**but it didn't work** and you get an error telling you that global styles are deprecated, I fixed it [like this](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/master/docs/upgrading/0.4.0-0.5.0.md#migrate-from-global-icon-library-to-faiconlibrary).

I created a new `icon.module.ts` and imported it in the `shared-libs.module.ts`.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FontAwesomeModule, FaIconLibrary } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { fas } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FontAwesomeModule
  ]
})
export class IconsModule {
  constructor(library: FaIconLibrary) {
    library.addIconPacks(fas);
  }
}
```

I hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

For jhipster version 7, file to modify is now located at :
src/main/webapp/app/config/icon-loader.ts